# How to Log/ View AWS Java SDK HTTP(S) Requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, https

I am developing a Spring Boot Application that uses HTTPS Only. I am using AWS services and the corresponding AWS Java SDK. How can I view the HTTP(S) request that the java sdk methods call on the backend of my application? I want to make sure when doing uploads to S3, etc, that everything is done over HTTPS only as the security of this application is important. A little confused on how to see when the backend of the application is interacting with the AWS services. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS uses HTTPS by default for all communications, and gives you options (such as VPC endpoints) that prevent traffic from leaving the AWS VPC.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a reference in the Java SDK documentation that says it follows this practice. You *can* find guarantees for individual services (for example, [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/network-isolation.html)). And it's implied that the SDK uses TLS by the [page that describes how to enforce using TLS 1.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/security-java-tls.html).

However, if you really want to be sure, you need to [enable logging at the wire level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/logging-slf4j.html#sdk-java-logging-verbose).

---

*Update in response to comment:*

I ran the following program with debugging on:

```
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    throws Exception
    {
        S3Client client = S3Client.builder().build();
        
        for (Bucket bucket : client.listBuckets().buckets())
        {
            System.out.println(bucket.name());
        }
    }
```

Looking at the logs, it's definitely making an HTTPS connection:

```
2021-11-17 17:51:24,802 [main] DEBUG request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host=s3.amazonaws.com, port=443, encodedPath=/, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent], queryParameters=[])
...
2021-11-17 17:51:24,832 [main] DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2021-11-17 17:51:24,839 [main] DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2021-11-17 17:51:24,840 [main] DEBUG MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://s3.amazonaws.com:443
2021-11-17 17:51:24,871 [main] DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.251.102:443
2021-11-17 17:51:24,871 [main] DEBUG SdkTlsSocketFactory - Connecting socket to s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.251.102:443 with timeout 2000
2021-11-17 17:51:24,902 [main] DEBUG SdkTlsSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
```

That's followed by the TLS negotiation, and then the actual request. One thing that *may* be confusing, if you're not familiar with the HTTP protocol, is this:

```
2021-11-17 17:51:25,022 [main] DEBUG MainClientExec - Executing request GET / HTTP/1.1
```

That's the HTTP request line, and the "HTTP/1.1" indicates the protocol version. This information is sent over the secure connection.

Comment: I enabled logging at the wire level. It appears the communications to S3 and DynamoDB are both using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Not sure why because I thought the default was HTTPS.

Comment: @DavisWard - I've updated my answer to show extracts from the logs. If you're seeing something different, please update your question with your log output.

Comment: That exactly answers my question. My AWS services are communicating over HTTPS. Thank you so much!